# Virtualbox - Route a VM through a secure proxy

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, security

I have Virtualbox 4.3.6 running on Windows 7 Pro. I have various Linux VMs, I'd like to know if there is any way I can configure virtualbox not to use the default internet access the laptop has (work network, home network, public wifi) and route traffic securely through a linux server I have with a static IP.

Can anyone advise how to do this? I have searched and searched and can't find any advice

Comment: Run TOR within the VM?

Comment: @Zoredache I won't be able to connect to tor from work.

Comment: I suspect that this question is a duplicate, but is it a duplicate of *that* question?  That question is about how to get the guest to use the same proxy that the host is already using.   This question is about getting the guest to use a proxy that is independent of the host’s network connection.   Can you identify which of the answers to that question will solve this OP’s problem?